# Proving $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt a\sqrt b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am currently in high school and we are studying radicals. I had asked my math teacher why $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ (for all a,b>0) and he tries to prove it by arguing that $a^{1/2}*b^{1/2}=(ab)^{1/2}$ (an exponent law). However, I find this proof problematic since $x^{1/2}$ is simply *defined* as $\sqrt{x}$, so the reasoning is circular.

My view is that $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ because once we square both sides we get $ab=ab$. Since we're obviously referring to the positive root, and the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is injective, it necessarily follows that the original expressions $\sqrt{ab}$ and $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ are equivalent because for injective functions it is not possible to map distinct elements in the domain to the same element in the range ($ab$). Hence they are equivalent expressions.

My question therefore is, is my proof valid and/or rigorous (I find it convincing but maybe it's wrong; I just want to be clear) and secondly was my teacher's proof correct?

Comment: Your proof is more conceptual, that is, better. The proof offered by your teacher is fine if the exponent law has been **proved**, and not merely asserted.

Comment: Supposing $\sqrt x$  rigourously defined, your proof is fine. However it relies on the definition of $\sqrt x$. There are are various definitions. The handiest one is  $$\sqrt x=\mathrm e^{\tfrac 12\ln x}.$$

Comment: Squaring both sides still requires law of exponents because you still have to use the law that permits us to do this : $(\sqrt{a} \sqrt{b})^2=(\sqrt{a})^2(\sqrt{b})^2 $ @AndréNicolas

Comment: @randomgirl: It is integer exponents, which is a little easier to establish.

Comment: @randomgirl I believe that's just the associativity law for multiplying real numbers, not an exponent rule.

Comment: Hmm... I was always taught that was an exponent rule. (And it seems all sites list it as an exponent rule.)

Comment: @randomgirl: If you define $x^2 = x \cdot x$, then $(xy)^2 = (xy)(xy) = x(y(xy)) = x((yx)y) = x((xy)y) = x(x(yy)) = (xx)(yy) = x^2y^2$, by only commutativity and associativity.

Comment: There may be an exponent rule that subsumes that, but that part alone doesn't require anything more than associativity and commutativity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could we proceed along the following lines, as long as we restrict ourselves to the positive reals?  We observe $\sqrt{x}$ to be the unique positive real number $r$ such that $r \cdot r = x$.

Let $m = \sqrt{a}, n = \sqrt{b}$.  Then $m \cdot m = a, n \cdot n = b$, and

$$
\begin{align}
a \cdot b & = (m \cdot m) \cdot b \\
          & = m \cdot (m \cdot b) \\
          & = m \cdot (m \cdot (n \cdot n)) \\
          & = m \cdot ((m \cdot n) \cdot n) \\
          & = m \cdot ((n \cdot m) \cdot n) \\
          & = m \cdot (n \cdot (m \cdot n)) \\
          & = (m \cdot n) \cdot (m \cdot n)
\end{align}
$$

where we rely on the associativity and commutativity of multiplication.  Hence $\sqrt{ab} = m \cdot n = \sqrt{a} \cdot \sqrt{b}$.

Comment: Okay, I guess that works as well! Thanks :-)

Comment: That's basically your idea, put symbolically (and a couple of steps spelled out a bit more).