# How can one prove that $\sqrt{ 2} \cdot \sqrt{ 3} = \sqrt{ 6}$?

Tags: proof-verification

I have already proved that $\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{2}=2$ so I hope I can now use $\sqrt{3}\cdot \sqrt{3}=3$ and the same for 6.
The exercise comes from Stillwell: Mathematics and its History. The other exercises have not been complicated so probably the solution to proving $\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{2}=2$ I borrowed from Martin K was way over the top. But it cannot be adapted, I think, to this one where the roots are not of the same number.
Here is my attempt:
$r^2=2, s^2=3$.

$r\cdot r=2$ implies $r=\sqrt{2}$ and $s\cdot s=3$ 
implies $s=\sqrt{3}$

I also know that $\sqrt{6}\cdot \sqrt{6}=6$.

$r^2\cdot s^2=6$  so  $(rs)^2=6$
This implies that $(\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3})^2=\sqrt{6}\cdot \sqrt{6}$

Which I am not sure about, but hope, implies that $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{6}$

Comment: It is correct .

Comment: Compare your proof with [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1274936/proving-sqrtab-sqrt-a-sqrt-b) from this site. Then you will see it.

Comment: Of course, the point is that You use commutativity and associativity while stating $r^2s^2=(rs)^2=2.3=6$

Comment: I should have said that the context is Dedekind's proof (which I have been unable to find online. I'd love to see it.)  so the commutativity of roots might not be assumable. My problem was largely concerning how much might be assumed.

Comment: @Kang Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @gimusi The original problem has not been solved. I need to study Dedekind's proof to answer it myself. But I've had too much else to do. Should I just accept the best answer to close it?

Answer (score 3):

Let $a, b > 0$ then we need to prove that $ \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b} = \sqrt{ab} $
If we do not prove axiomatically, then we can do this:
Since we have positive numbers, their squares will also be equal.
$$ (\sqrt{a} \cdot \sqrt{b})^2 =_{?} (\sqrt{ab})^2 $$
and, $ (xy)^2 = x^2y^2 $, then $\sqrt{a}^2\cdot\sqrt{b}^2 = ab $ 
by the definition of a root, we obtain equality.

Comment: I want to note that the equality of squares of positive numbers is equal if and only if these numbers are equal. (Therefore the proof is correct)

Comment: This is not the answer I am looking for either (see comment above) but it does clarify exactly what sort of answer would satisfy me so it, too, has helped!

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$a=\sqrt{2}\implies a^2=2$$

$$b=\sqrt{3}\implies b^2=3$$

then

$$(ab)^2=6\implies ab=\sqrt{6}$$

Comment: Your huge reputation emboldens me to ask if you know a source of Dedekind's proof? I may not be able to understand it but I see now (see comments either side of your answer) that only something along those lines will satisfy me.

Comment: Sorry it wasn’t clear by your OP, I’ll take a look! Bye

Answer (score 2):

Let $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3} = x$.

Substitute $\sqrt{2} = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\sqrt{3} = \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{3}}$. Then we should have: $$\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{3}}\right) = \sqrt{6}.\tag1$$ Note that the $LHS$ (*Left Hand Side* of the equation) is equal to $\dfrac{6}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}}$. It follows, then, that: $$\begin{align} \frac{6}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}} &=\sqrt{6} \\ &\Downarrow \\ \frac{6}{x} &= \sqrt{6}.\end{align}$$ For you to have made your substitutions in Eq. $(1)$, it must follow that $x = \sqrt{6}$.

> $$\therefore \sqrt{2}\sqrt{3} = \sqrt{6}.\tag*{$\bigcirc$}$$

Comment: This does help me to pin-point exactly what I am looking for and why I am not satisfied with my proof. I see I must, after all, attempt to use Dedekind cuts.

Comment: @Kang your proof is fine. It is correct and quite nice, imho. I was just giving a suggestion as to another proof like the other answers :)

Comment: At the risk of offending against protocol: thank you. All the proofs offered were helpful and enabled me to see not why I was dissatisfied with my proof in particular (sorry I wasn't clear on that) but that all these proofs seem to assume more than I suspect Stillwell wants us to assume at that point. Hence the reference to Dedekind, whose cuts are the subject of the section from which the exercise comes.